# DataAnnotation RegularExpression .NET - Problemas con expresiones regulares

Tags: .net, regex, dataannotations

La verdad que estoy hace rato dando vueltas con el tema. Probé distintas maneras de levantar una validación básica que filtre cadenas que no tengan formato de números decimales. Corroboré mis expresiones en la página de regex [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://regexr.com/)

Les presento dos expresiones básicas que probé:

```
@"^\d*\.\d+$"

@"^(\d)+\.(\d)+$"
```

Ninguna de las dos me funcionó.

El código en .net:
DTO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPI_01.DTO
{
    public class deviceDTO
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\d)+\.(\d)+$", ErrorMessage = @"La coordenada debe ser representada en formato de número decimal")]
        public Nullable<decimal> latitud { get; set; }
        //[RegularExpression(@"^(\d)+\.(\d)+$", ErrorMessage = @"La coordenada debe ser representada en formato de número decimal")]
        public Nullable<decimal> longitud { get; set; }
        //[RegularExpression(@"^(\d)+\.(\d)+$", ErrorMessage = @"La coordenada debe ser representada en formato de número decimal")]
        public Nullable<decimal> altitud { get; set; }

        public Nullable<bool> isDisabled { get; set; } //isDisabled - is_disabled 
    }
}
```

Método POST:

```
[Route("api/device")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostDeviceAsync([FromBody] deviceDTO devDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

Un poco más de contexto:

Cuando realizo la solicitud desde el postman me retorna el siguiente JSON:

```
{
    "Message": "La solicitud no es válida.",
    "ModelState": {
        "devDto.latitud": [
            "La coordenada debe ser representada en formato de número decimal"
        ]
    }
}
```

Por lo que se puede verificar que no matchea con las distintos valores con los que he probado:

```
51.515 
"51.515" 
50 
50.1 
5000 
50,55 
50*54
```

Comment: Añado una pista, otras expresiones regulares si me anduvieron sin problemas. Pareciera ser que el problema esta en el " \. "